# C++ cannot rewrite shared memory in my windows app. It allocates new memory

Tags: c++, shared-memory

Shared memory in C++ is new thing for me, still learning, and now I found that it doesn't work how I expected. I want to implement class called CharBuffer which has char array mapped to shared memory by CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile functions:

```
HANDLE hBuffer = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, size, shmBufferName); 
char * buffer = (char *) MapViewOfFile(hBuffer, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, size);
```

Adding bytes to buffer is implemented by calling CharBuffer function "add":

```
void CharBuffer::add(char * data, size_t size) {
    memcpy(&buffer[0], &data[0], size);
}
```

There is no check for data size but this is no problem, it is just my test app for learning with shared memory.
This is OK, I can add bytes to buffer or read from buffer successfully - no error, no problem. This I am doing with **first** instance of CharBuffer.

But now I'd like to open shared memory with **second** instance of CharBuffer and read or rewrite the data in shared memory. For open and map memory I use:

```
HANDLE hBuffer = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, shmBufferName);
char * buffer = (char *) MapViewOfFile(hBuffer, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, size);
```

There is no error during opening. Now I am getting to my problem. In **first** instance I copied 64 MB to shared memory. When I try read them byte-by-byte with **second** instance which has correctly mapped shared memory (it prints data OK) but in Resource monitor I can see I have two times more memory - 128 MB. After first adding data the memory took 64 MB but during printing data via second instance the memory is increased by next 64 memory.

The same problem is writing data to memory with second instance.

My goal is to have limited shared memory and work with it (read/write) by two or more instances of CharBuffer. Can you please explain me where could be the problem or how I can implement what I want?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: When you say "second instance" do you mean another copy of your program?

Comment: No. Just create CharBuffer bfr1 then call bfr1.add(data, size) and then create CharBuffer bfr2 and read the data. All in main function of one copy of program.

Comment: You've opened two mappings to the same shared mapping. Try using the same mapping HANDLE for both.

Comment: You mean use one HANDLE which is shared by two CharBuffers? I will try it.

Comment: You have the same memory occupying two address blocks. That's not a problem, but seems useless. The purpose of shared memory is to let two or more processes access the same data.

Comment: Why do you need CreateFileMapping for that? Why dont you just share your pointer (to some allocated memory) between instances of your CharBuffer?

Comment: This is just example app. I want to learn shared memory as a way for exchange data between two or more threads.

Comment: @babusek - then you do not have to do anything remotely special - it's already all shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used memory mapped files to lower memory consumption. I think that your problem is that MapViewOfFile always returns pointer to unique address space, which will modify the same pages in you page file. I tried to find prove of that in MSDN, all I found is this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx

which I suppose explains it:

> As mentioned above, you can have multiple views of the same
>   memory-mapped file, and they can overlap. But what about mapping two
>   identical views of the same memory-mapped file? After learning how to
>   unmap a view of a file, you could come to the conclusion that it would
>   not be possible to have two identical views in a single process
>   because their base address would be the same, and you wouldn't be able
>   to distinguish between them. This is not true. Remember that the base
>   address returned by either the MapViewOfFile or the MapViewOfFileEx
>   function is not the base address of the file view. Rather, it is the
>   base address in your process where the view begins. So mapping two
>   identical views of the same memory-mapped file will produce two views
>   having different base addresses, but nonetheless identical views of
>   the same portion of the memory-mapped file.
>
> ***The point of this little exercise is to emphasize that every view of a
>   single memory-mapped file object is always mapped to a unique range of
>   addresses in the process***. The base address will be different for each
>   view. For that reason the base address of a mapped view is all that is
>   required to unmap the view.

so MapViewOfFile returns addresses to memory that once committed will have assigned its own physical memory, which actually increases your process memory consumption - as you have described.

[edit]

actually, I am starting to see that even thought both MapViewOffFile returns addresses to unique virtual address spaces, they are both backed by the same physical RAM pages. You can read on this in Windows Via c/c++ in `Memory-Mapped Files and Coherence`:

> If multiple processes are mapping views of a single data file, the
>   data is still coherent because there is still only one instance of
>   each page of RAM within the data file—it's just that the pages of RAM
>   are mapped into multiple process address spaces.

this is also proved by the trick in following blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/07/55194.aspx

the fact that resource monitor shows you memory consumption too high each time you access your view of file, is that it shows working set size which to my understanding might show shared memory twice.

Comment: Thanks for your description of problem. But now I tried this: I used just one HANDLE for both CharBuffers, after adding data I did UnmapViewOfFile and CloseHandle, then in next CharBuffer opened the same handle and correctly read the data from buffer. The memory was again increased during reading but it reached only to 64 MB because of previous call of UnmapViewOfFile which decreased the memory. Is this correct way how to solve my problem?

Comment: I think that once you CloseHandle to handle from CreateFileMapping, you release also reserved pages from page file. So dont CloseHandle.

Comment: Yes, I thing the same but I don't understand why I still could read the results.

Comment: maybe it was still in your page file? - I updated my answer, It looks like your initial assumption was actually right